# C# copying an immutable struct with modification?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct

I have several immutable `struct`s that contain info e.g.

```cs
public struct Human {
  public readonly string Name;
  public readonly int Age;
  // ... 50 other variables that describe a human
}
```

Now I want to clone a `Human` struct, but change 1 value only. I can of course do it like this:

```cs
var newSelf = new Human(
  oldSelf.Name,
  oldSelf.Age + 1,
  // ... 50 more lines here
)
```

But as you can see it'll be really tedious to type `oldSelf.XYZ` 50 times for every single struct I made.

So I'm looking for something like this:

```cs
// copy all variable from oldSelf to a new struct, but change the name and increase Age by 1
var newSelf = oldSelf.CloneWithModification(("Name", "Valeria"), ("Age", oldSelf.Age + 1));
```

I am not too keen on a `struct` precisely. What I need is actually just:

- An immutable type that can be passed to another module (without worrying about the receiver modifying content affecting sender).
- Easy cloning with small modifications.

Comment: Take a look at [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) available in C# 9.

Comment: Why do you store the `Age` as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`record`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), introduced in C# 9, or if being a value type is also a requirement, use [`record struct`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs), introduced in C# 10.

```
public record Human {
  public string Name { get; init; }
  public int Age { get; init; }
  // ... 50 other variables that describe a human
}
```

Then you can use the [`with` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) to create a copy of a `Human`, with only some properties changed. Note that this uses the `init` accessor.

```
Human human = ...
var newHuman = human with { Age = human.Age + 1 }; // this creates a copy
```

Comment: Thanks, `record` seems precisely the thing I need. But I'll need to update my Unity version in order to use C# 9. So sad...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to C# 9.0 or above, I support using the `with` operator as mentioned in the other answers.

Below C# 9.0, you can consider using the `MemberwiseClone()` method. It is protected, so you can only call it from another method, not outside the class. For example:

```
public struct Human {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    
    public Human(string name, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public Human WithAge(int age) {
        var result = (Human)this.MemberwiseClone();
        result.Age = age;
        return result;
    }
```

Then

```
var older = new Human("AVAVT", 70);
var younger = older.WithAge(18);

// Prints: "Younger is 18 years old."
System.Console.WriteLine($"Younger is {younger.Age} years old.");
```

Comment: Yeah `MemberwiseClone()` is what I'm using as a workaround. But your `WithAge` won't work, `Age`'s setter is private so `result.Age` can't be changed.

Comment: Why not? If `result` is a `Human`, you can access from within a `Human` method. `private` does not imply `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `record` you can follow the [following pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/)

```
public Human WithName(string value)
   => value == Name
      ? this
      : new Human(value, Age, ...);

public Human WithAge(int value)
   => value == Age
      ? this
      : new Human(Name, value, ...);

...
```